# how to transfer 2 dimensional pointer outside a function so that the memory pointed by the pointer can be accessed?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, parameter-passing

This is a C programming problem.

I need to transfer a 2-d pointer outside of a function `f()` so that other functions can access the memory allocated inside `f()`.

but, I got Segmentation fault at "error here" when i > 1.

How to do 2-d pointer so that the input argument can really be used by outside function? I doubt that `*ba = (dp[0]);`  has something wrong.

why ?

```
typedef struct {
    char* al;   /* '\0'-terminated C string */
    int   sid;
} strtyp ;

strtyp *Getali(void)
{  
    strtyp  *p = (strtyp *) malloc(sizeof(strtyp )) ;
    p->al = "test al";
    p->sid = rand();
    return p; 
}

strtyp *GetNAl(void)
{
    strtyp *p = (strtyp *) malloc(sizeof(strtyp )) ;
    p->al = "test a";
    p->sid = rand();
    return p; 
}

int *getIDs2(strtyp   **ba, int *aS , int *iSz)
{
    int  *id  = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 8) ;   
    *idS = 8 ; 
    int length = 10;
    int i  ;
    strtyp   **dp  = (strtyp  **) malloc(sizeof(strtyp*)*length) ;  
    for(i = 0 ; i < length ; ++i)
    {
        dp[i] = GetNAl();
        printf("(*pd)->ali is %s ", (*pd[i]).ali );
        printf("(*pd)->sid is %d ", (*pd[i]).sid );
        printf("\n");
    }
    *ba = (dp[0]); 
    for(i = 0 ; i < length ; ++i)
    {
        printf("(*ba)->ali is %s ", (*ba[i]).ali ); // error here
        printf("(*ba)->sid is %d ", (*ba[i]).sid );
        printf("\n");
    }

    *aIs = length ;
    return  id; 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to set a `strtyp **` variable in the calling function, the argument must be a pointer to this type - `strtype ***`.  So your function would look like:

```
int *getIDs2(strtyp ***ba, int *aS, int *iSz)
{
    /* ... */
    strtyp **pd  = malloc(sizeof pd[0] * length) ;  

    for(i = 0 ; i < length ; ++i)
    {
        pd[i] = GetNAl();
        printf("(*pd)->ali is %s ", pd[i]->ali );
        printf("(*pd)->sid is %d ", pd[i]->sid );
        printf("\n");
    }

    *ba = pd;

    for(i = 0 ; i < length ; ++i)
    {
        printf("(*ba)->ali is %s ", (*ba)[i]->ali );
        printf("(*ba)->sid is %d ", (*ba)[i]->sid );
        printf("\n");
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

...and your caller would look like:

```
strtyp **x;

getIDs2(&x, ...);
```